# Union of an increasing sequence of sets without a universal set

Tags: field-theory

Assume we have sets $E_0,E_1,E_2,\dots$ such that $E_0 \subset E_1 \subset \cdots$ and we have no knowledge of a fixed set $U$ such that $E_i \subset U$ for all $i$. Apparently it is possible that the union $E=\cup_{i=0}^\infty E_i$ might not be a set. Why do we need $U$ for $E$ to be a set?

The question comes from a remark to Proposition 4.24 in [J.S. Milne Field Theory course notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html):

> Proposition 4.24:
> The field $\mathbb{F}{}_{p}$ has an algebraic closure
> $\mathbb{F}{}$.
>
> Proof:
> Choose a sequence of integers $1=n_{1}<n_{2}<n_{3}<\cdots$ such that
> $n_{i}|n_{i+1}$ for all $i$, and every integer $n$ divides some $n_{i}$. For
> example, let $n_{i}=i!$. Define the fields $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i}}}$
> inductively as follows: $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{1}}}=\mathbb{F}{}_{p}$;
> $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i}}}$ is the splitting field of $X^{p^{n_{i}}}-X$ over
> $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i-1}}}$. Then, $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{1}}}\subset \mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{2}}}\subset\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{3}}}\subset\cdots$, and we
> define $\mathbb{F}{}=\bigcup\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i}}}$. As a union of a chain
> of fields algebraic over $\mathbb{F}{}_{p}$, it is again a field algebraic
> over $\mathbb{F}{}_{p}$. Moreover, every polynomial in $\mathbb{F}{}_{p}[X]$
> splits in $\mathbb{F}{}$, and so it is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}{}$
> (by 1.44).
>
> Remark 4.25:
> Since the $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n}}$ are not subsets of a fixed set,
> forming the union requires explanation. Let $S$ be the disjoint union of the
> $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n}}$. For $a,b\in S$, set $a\sim b$ if $a=b$ in one of the
> $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n}}$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and we let
> $\mathbb{F}{}=S/\sim$.

If the union $\bigcup\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i}}}$ is not a set, then why is the disjoint union $S$ of the $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n}}$ a set? Or is it not a problem that it isn't?

(There is also a union of sets in a similar situation in Emil Artin's proof on p.87 "Third proof of the existence of algebraic closures" without any corresponding remark.)

Comment: The problem isn't $\bigcup\mathbb{F}_{p^{n_i}}$ is not a set, but what exactly you mean by this union.  The disjoint union exists by the axiom (schema) of replacement.

Comment: So $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{1}}}\subset
\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{2}}}\subset\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{3}}}\subset\cdots$ doesn't mean a sequence of subsets, but that there exists a sequence of field homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i}}} \to \mathbb{F}{}_{p^{n_{i+1}}}$ and that's why the meaning of the union needs clarification? If there is a real sequence of sets $E_0 \subset E_1 \subset \cdots$ then $E=\cup_{i} E_i$ is always a set by the axiom schema of replacement and the axiom of union?